# Gitstats Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, git, gnuplot

While working in Eclipse with .git is noticed Eclipse makes a nice folder for gitstats in the project folder. 
I attemted to use these files to generate gitstats output, but i cant seem to get it done.
Can someone explain to me how to use these files to get gitstats output.

[image: The project folder]

[image: The gitstats folder]

I do have Python, Gnuplot and git installed. All the latest version.

I do understand that i somehow have to run python on the gitstats file. But after hours of trying is still cant manage to find out how. Probably I am doing something simpel wrong cause i cant find much information on how to use GitStats, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours i finnaly got it working, since i noticed some people had the same issue here the solution.

Eclipse wil just clone your git repository as you would with git it self.

When using gitstats make sure you install python27 and not python33. 
Set up your PATH variables to python27 files.
Install GNUplot and also add the PATH variable.

If you use windows insted of linux, in order to easely use gitstats run it in git bash. Since gitbash is Shell script and does suppor WC. CMD does not support WC unless you got Unix installed.

If you still have issues running gitbash, recheck PATH varaibles since that is 9 out of 10 times the issue.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You should not put the gitstats repository under your project directory (I'm assuming the upper screenshot is of your project directory). You can clone it to a separate directory, and then pass your personal project directory as a parameter, as the [doc/INSTALL](https://github.com/hoxu/gitstats/blob/master/doc/INSTALL) instructs:

```
./gitstats /mnt/src/git/project ~/public_html/project
```

That is a command that needs to be run in a terminal/shell. Of course, you could add an `External Tools Configuration` in eclipse for it, but not sure if it's worth the trouble, unless you want to run it very often.

Comment: Thanks so far, getting there. getting an error though:
When i run ./gitstats ../ /output/

I get the error:
File "./gitstats" line 50
print >> + | .join(cmds)

Syntax error : invalid syntax